# Can't compare Unicode characters from different version of Unicode. SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, nvarchar

I have 2 tables

Table1 :  EmployeeID nvarchar(20),
          EmployeeName nvarchar(50)

*(created by somebody few years ago.)*

Table2 :  EmployeeID nvarchar(20),
          EmployeeName nvarchar(50)

*(I recently created to update the application.)*

However, it seem that i can't compare some unicode characters. Ex: 'Ð' in 'Ð123'.
I tried this query but it not work for those characters.

```
update Table2 set
Table2.EmployeeName = (select Table1.EmployeeName from Table1
where Table1.EmployeeID like Table2.EmployeeID)
```

and also

```
update Table2 set
Table2.EmployeeName = (select Table1.EmployeeName from Table1
where Table1.EmployeeID like N'%' + Table2.EmployeeID +'%')
```

but it still not work. Both tables have this 'Ð123' in EmployeeID column, and they are all unicode type. So i think that because of the different version of unicode may cause this problem, but i don't know how to solve it. Hope you can help.

Comment: Please explain what “not work” means. It is extremely unlikely that “different version of unicode” has anything to do with your problem; it is much more likely the database collation was different when the earlier table was created.

Comment: It return 0 rows effect. But i find the way to temporarily fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find a temporarily way to fix this by load table1 and table2 to c# application and then compare and update to back to database.